# How do I retrive unique values using javascript where the response is in jason

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This I have tried but this does'nt work it is taking duplicates also.How can I retrive only the distinct values from jason using javascript.

```
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
                        var data = value['customerName'];
                        var uniqueNames = [];

                            if (uniqueNames.indexOf(data,uniqueNames) === -1) {
                                uniqueNames.push(data);


                            console.log(uniqueNames);
                        }

                       options += '<option value="' + value['id'] + '">' +value['customerName'] + 
                         '</option>';

                    });
                    $("#customername").html(options);
                    $("#customername").change();
                }
            });
```

Comment: what does the jason[sic] look like?

Comment: `uniqueNames.indexOf(data,uniqueNames)` the second argument to indexOf is NOT an array - perhaps that's an issue

Comment: { id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2018 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2017 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2017 }

Comment: that's the sort of thing that you should put ... IN THE QUESTION where it is readable

Comment: Also, your result has no properties called `customerName`, just `name`